# Attendance - Count total number of days each person showed up

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, countif

Please see the table (spreadsheet) below. I'm trying to create a formula that will help me determine how many total days each person actually entered the building. You will see within the table some of the individuals entered multiple times in one day. In the event that occurs that should only count for one. The formula should return the following results

```
Jane Doe - 2
John Smith - 4
James Williams - 2
```

[image: Attendance Table]

Answer (score 1):

Use an array formula like in [this example](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2011/07/12/count-unique-distinct-values-that-meet-multiple-criteria-in-excel/).

So for your data:

[image: EntryData]

You could copy and paste the values from column C to Column E, perform a Remove Duplicates on it, then put the formula `=SUM(IF(E2=$C$2:$C$17,1/(COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$17,E2,$B$2:$B$17,$B$2:$B$17)),0))` into `F2`, apply it as an Array Formula (hold `CTRL`+`SHIFT`, press `ENTER`, then release all keys) and copy it down:

[image: EntrySummary]

Obviously if your data range runs beyond row 17, extend the static ranges in the formula accordingly.